# What's the COMPLETE way to request the user to enable accessibility services?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have looked in stackoverflow and found only the following:

```
Intent changeSettings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(changeSettings, 0);
```

How do I add to this code the ability to check whether the permission is already granted? And what exactly does "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()" do and how does it work? Same question for "onRequestPermissionResult".

Thank you.

Comment: "And what exactly does "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()" do and how does it work? Same question for "onRequestPermissionResult"." -- neither of those are related to requesting accessibility access. Those are for ordinary `dangerous` permissions, not special app access.

Comment: Oh. I just saw them somewhere and assumed they should be used to tell the user why he/she should enable the service or something. Btw what qualifies as a dangerous permission? Like access to internal storage?

Comment: Contacts, GPS, etc. all require dangerous permissions. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare so what are the bells and whistles to use with requesting the user to enable accessibility service?

Comment: AFAIK, you are doing the right thing with your `Intent`, in terms of steering the user to enable your accessibility service. I have not implemented such a service, and I do not know off the cuff if there is a better-targeted `Intent` or what APIs you would use to find out if the user enabled your accessibility service. I was mostly focusing on the fact that `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` and `onRequestPermissionResult()` were not related.